# How to get path's parameters in url's breadcrumb in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, breadcrumbs, routeparams

I'm working with Vue

In my app's router, I'd like to use path's get parameters in breadcrumb's URL.

I'd like to do something like this :

```
  {
      path: 'pages/gestion/region/:reg',
      name: 'gestion-depa',
      component: () => import('@/views/pages/MyPage.vue'),
      meta: {
        breadcrumb: [
          { title: 'Home', url: '/' },
          { title: 'region', active: true, url:"/pages/list/:reg" },//Here i want to use my params get, but it doesn't work 
          { title: 'dep', active: false }
        ],
        pageTitle: 'Gestion',
        rule: 'editor',
        requiresAuth: true,
      }
    },
```

My breadcrumps redirect to /pages/list/:reg, but I need something like /pages/list/5

Can someone have an idea ?

Thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `beforeEnter` to update the meta:

```js
meta: {
...
},
beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
  to.meta.breadcrumb[1].url = `/pages/list/${to.params.reg}`
  next();
}
```